# How to add conditional statements on android.bp

Tags: android-soong

I'm custom a module.
Android.bp
cc_binary{
name:"gzip",
default:["gzip_default"],
static_libs:[...]
}

Android.bp don't support if statement.
How I can make like this on android.bp?
If target_build a

cc_binary{
name:"gzip",
default:["gzip_default"],
static_libs:[...]
}

Endif

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What does target_build mean for you? Show example.

You just add this module in device tree configuration file as "PRODUCT_PACKAGES += gzip" or not whether you do not need this one.